Importing images in ColabTurtle or ColabTurtlePlus?
I want to make a program in Google Colab in Python to solve a maze using the Turtle library. Upload the image of a maze, then program the turtle to solve it - something like this:
from turtle import *

#setup info
speed("fast")
shape("turtle")
shapesize(1)
bgpic('maze.png')

#movement
penup()
goto(-110, 50)
#continue solving the maze here

It seems like Google Colab doesn't support turtle, but it DOES support ColabTurtle and ColabTurtlePlus. The code would need to look more like this in Colab:
!pip3 install ColabTurtlePlus

from ColabTurtlePlus.Turtle import *

clearscreen()
initializeTurtle()

#setup info
shape("turtle")
shapesize(1)
bgpic('maze.png')

#movement
penup()
goto(-110, 50)
#continue solving the maze here

I can see from the documentation there is a way to set the background color, but when I try to use bgpic('maze.png') in Colab, I get this error:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-073cd39b2bb7> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 shape("turtle")
      6 shapesize(1)
----> 7 bgpic('maze.png')
      8 
      9 #movement

NameError: name 'bgpic' is not defined

Is there a way to set an image as the background in Colab?
